# Filling new column with information from a list in multiple excel files using Python

Tags: excel

I need to add a column to 40 excel files. The new column in each file will be filled with a name.

This is what I have:

files=[16686_Survey.xlsx, 16687_Survey.xlsx, 16772_Survey.xlsx, ...] (40 files with more than 200 rows each)

filenames=['name1', 'name2', 'name3', ...] (40 names)

I need to add a column to each excel file and write its corresponding name along the new column.

With the following code I got what I need for one file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('16686_Survey.xlsx') 
df.insert(0, "WellName", "Name1")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('16686_Survey.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, index = False)
writer.save()
```

But it would be inefficient if I do it 40 times, and I would like to learn how to use a loop to address this type of problem because I have been in the same situation many times.

[The image is what I got with the code above. The first table in the image is what I have. The second table is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knxgp.png)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure I understand your question but I think you're looking for this:

```py
import pandas as pd

files=['16686_Survey.xlsx', '16687_Survey.xlsx', '16772_Survey.xlsx', ...] 
filenames=['name1', 'name2', 'name3', ...] 

for excel_file, other_name in zip(files, filenames):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file) 
    df.insert(0, "WellName", other_name)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file)
    df.to_excel(writer, index = False)
    writer.save()
```

I combined both the lists (I assumed they were the same length) using the `zip` function. The zip function takes items from the lists one by one and combines them so that all the first items are together and all the second and so forth.